# Windows Server Backup says the filename, directory name, or volume label is incorrect when adding another destination drive to the backup

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 installed and running. I created a full server backup to an external portable drive (MyBook by WD). It scheduled and has been running with no errors for a week. I purchased another MyBook (same size too) to swap out so we have an offsite backup in rotation. I plugged the new drive in and ran through the wizard to add this drive as a destination. It gets to the end and says "The filename, directory name, or volume label is incorrect." Then says the backup has not been modified.

If I look in the disk managment, the external drive has been formatted and labeled exactly like the first drive, only with Disk_02 instead of Disk_01.

This is the second drive it has happened on. We had another drive that I assumed was just going bad so we bought this new one to replace it.

Edit: Also, this type of scenario was working just fine on a Windows Server 2008 machine. The boot drive went bad so I decided to start over with R2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by plugging both removable drives in while adding the second backup drive. I didn't need to do this in Server 2008, I guess R2 requires it or it's a bug.

Comment: It worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Server Backup Command line.

1. Use command line or UI to create backup schedule with a disk as backup target.
2. Detach your first disk
3. Use `WBADMIN` Command line for adding another disk to schedule.

Sample Usage:

```
WBADMIN ENABLE BACKUP -addtarget:{aa123d14-bba0-1dd9-0d93-80aaaa6bbb63}
```

Note that the `AddTarget` parameter takes disk ID which can be got by running `WBADMIN GET DISKS` command.

Comment: For anyone curious, on Windows 2008 R2 this problem and the solution scales to at least five drives.  However, I found that I was unable to set up more than two drives using Adding a Destination.  That is, I needed to start from scratch with all five drives simultaneously connected for it to work.